How to get Minswap "Pool composition" info from Cardano blockchain?
I am trying to find a way to get the Minswap liquidity pool data on the Cardano blockchain.
The pool info page (e.g. https://minswap.org/pools/min-ada) provides the following data:

LP policy ID: f5808c2c990d86da54bfc97d89cee6efa20cd8461616359478d96b4c
LP token name:
82e2b1fd27a7712a1a9cf750dfbea1a5778611b20e06dd6a611df7a643f8cb75

Is it possible to get the token reserves in the pool (section Pool composition) from the blockchain based on this data, as well as the token addresses that make up the pool's liquid pair (e.g. using 'pycardano' or another method)?

